# Como puedo crear un cookie en Django para mantener una vista específica?

Tags: javascript, django, aplicación-web

Tengo una vista de Django, donde el usuario puede elegir entre 2 "vistas" diferentes de una lista a través de un botón de alternancia. La vista de mapa donde se muestra un mapa con marcadores y alguna información y una vista de lista donde se muestra una lista con la misma información pero con una vista de lista.

Cuando el usuario hace clic en el botón para alternar entre una u otra opción, no hay problema, porque implementé una función onClick Javascript donde cambio el estilo de visualización, y eso funciona perfecto, el problema es cuando el usuario recarga la página.

Supone que puse por defecto la vista de mapa, pero el usuario cambia a la vista de lista haciendo clic en el botón de alternar, ahora si vuelve a cargar la página, la vista tendrá que ser la vista de lista, sé que puedo lograr esto usando una cookie, pero no sé cómo implementar la actualización de la cookie cada vez que el usuario hace clic en uno de los botones de alternancia con Javascript vanilla o en mi vista de Python.

Sé que una solución puede ser la creación de 2 vistas de Django, una "mapView" y otra "listView", así que cuando haces clic en los botones, te diriges a otra URL, pero quiero cargar toda la información y tener la posibilidad de hacerlo sin esta solución.

También subo un GIF de cómo funciona ahora mismo. Hice clic en la vista de mapa, recargué la página y volví a cambiar a la vista de lista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de diferentes formas, ojala puedas agregar parte del codigo que cambia la ventana para poder darte una respuesta bien formada. (1) puedes utilizar y manejar las vistas solo desde javascript utilizando las [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie). (2) Como mencionaste puedes trabajar desde python de igual manera, cambiando la vista que mostraras desde ahi utilizando [Cookies](https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-cookies-handling/#:~:text=Django%20has%20methods%20like%20set_cookie,to%20store%20in%20the%20cookie.) igualmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilice cookies de Javascript para guardar que vista el usuario hace click.